# IEnumString searching substrings - possible?

Tags: com, mfc

I've implemented auto completion to a combobox like this article shows. Is it possible to make it search for substrings instead of just the beginning of the words?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2371/IAutoComplete-and-custom-IEnumString-implementatio

I haven't found any way to customize how IEnumString/IAutoComplete compares the strings. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The built in search options help a bit but it is complete chaos. To find instring matches you need to set flag AcoWordFilter. But this will prevent from numbers being matched!! However, there is a trick to get the numbers to match: preced with a double-quote as in "3 to find a string containing or starting with "3". Some more chaos? In the AcoWordFilter you also need to prefix other characters not considered part of a "word", eg. you need to prefix parentheses with a " but then you will not find parentheses at the first position!
So the solution is either to create your own implementation of IAutoComplete or offer the user to switch between the modes (a bit awkward).
I dont think that the MS engineers are especially proud of such chaos. How about one more option: AcoSearchAnwhere?

Answer (score 1):

After retrieving the Edit control's `IAutoComplete` interface, query it for an [IAutoComplete2 interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776288.aspx). Calling its [SetOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776290.aspx) member you can disable prefix filtering by specifying the `ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING` [AUTOCOMPLETEOPTIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762479.aspx).

This is available on Windows Vista and later. If you need a solution that works with pre-Vista versions, you'll have to [write your own](http://web.archive.org/web/20130818144647/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301412.aspx).

Comment: Is "disable prefix filtering" a strange way of saying "look anywhere in the string for this text" ?

Comment: So then it would find "test" if I searched for "es" but not "toast"? I never tried that option since I thought it would display more than I wanted when it said "Always display all suggestions." :)

Comment: I tested it, and it does not work! It does as documentation says: "Always display all suggestions." so now it doesn't filter at all using the input text. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Mackan: I'm afraid, I misread your question. I'll revise the answer as soon as I find time.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to it, since I can't find a way of making it search substrings.. :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question at all. I suspect that the right answer to the question is that customising filtering is not possible in general. Adding `ACO_WORD_FILTER` is the probably the best option available.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How exactly does this not address the question? And why do you assume, that your proposed solution does? If that is the case, why have you decided against writing your own proposed answer? It's not like this question already had an accepted answer.

Comment: You yourself commented that you had misread the question. I suggest that you study the effect of `ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING`. You will find that it does not "make it search for substrings instead of just the beginning of the words" as requested in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Great! So now that you have all the information at hand, why not publish your own proposed answer (so that it is subject to voting)?

Comment: The other answer already does that. You'd best best off removing this misleading answer. You don't want to waste anybody else's time I guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Wouldn't voting be the way to let others know? Please visit the [help] to learn, how this site works.

Comment: I have voted. No need to patronise me. Doing so reflects on you not me. Why won't you [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28550603/edit) the clear error in the answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Perhaps, because I haven't found time to do so. It's funny that you ask not to be patronized, and then turn around to go patronizing random people.

Comment: Revenge downvoting is pretty inane, don't you agree? It's funny though, because I quite often see you commenting on answers that are wrong and suggesting that the author fixes them. When it's your answer that is wrong, you appear incapable of admitting fault. We all make mistakes. But we can only learn from them by admitting them. You are clearly very knowledgeable, and very clever, but your stubbornness holds you back. I have not patronised anyone to the best of my knowledge. If I have I will correct it. What did I do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *"you appear incapable of admitting fault"* - [Seriously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550132/ienumstring-searching-substrings-possible/28550603?noredirect=1#comment45427839_28550603)? Anyway, this discussion is over. When I find time, I will update my answer to address the question, which likely consists of implementing a custom `IEnumString` interface implementation, so this does take time.

Comment: I'm actually working on auto-complete at the moment. I can tell you that implementing a custom `IEnumString` won't change the way the filtering works. I appreciate your voting though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A custom `IEnumString` implementation can control, populate, and filter its own backing store for the suggestions. I have done this previously to implement custom filtering.

Comment: I look forward to seeing how you do this. That would be very useful. All I can see in `IEnumString` is enumeration.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You simply disable filtering in the standard auto-complete implementation, and simply feed the `IEnumString` interface with a pre-filtered collection.

Comment: And you keep on feeding new filtered `IEnumString` interfaces whenever the user types?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No. You keep updating the backing store. You don't hand out new interfaces on every keystroke.

Comment: And the control runs over the enumeration each time the content of the edit control changes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's an implementation detail (although a plausible choice). Not my job to make any assumptions there. My job is to provide an interface implementation that meets the documented contract.

Comment: If the strings are not re-enumerated then what you are proposing won't work. My quick experiment suggests that what you propose will not solve the problem. But then you say that you have done this in the past. So probably I misunderstand something. I will wait for your answer edit.